# Get 'unc' path in OSX of mounted share

Tags: python, macos, share, mount, unc

In python I am trying to get the 'unc' path or server path of a mounted share.
So I have a mounted share of:

```
/Volumes/D
```

How do I resolve to this with Python:

```
//192.168.0.7/D
```

Cheers.

Comment: OS X doesn't use UNC paths, so the question doesn't really make sense. Are you looking for a URL (e.g. afp://192.168.0.7/D), or maybe an alias (which isn't text, but a potentially-complex data structure)? What are you actually trying to accomplish (see [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378))?

Comment: I know that OSX doesnt use UNC paths, but I need to know the IP address of the network share to use somewhere else, I need to know the server it's on the url would work fine. Is there any way to do this please?

Comment: Can you parse the output of the `mount` command? Or `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into `df`, I came up with this which works excellent on OSX:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

df = Popen('df -P /Volumes/link/to/some/folder', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
serverAddress = df.stdout.readlines()[1:][0]
serverAddress = serverAddress.split('@')[1]
serverAddress = serverAddress.split('/')[0]
print serverAddress
```

Comment: I removed the use of `shell=True`, which is particularly dangerous with paths in the arguments (that can contain spaces, quotes, semicolons, ...).  Also, in practice you would try to have a more complete parsing of the mounted resource (e.g. user and share name would not be thrown away), and I wonder if this is unambiguous - how do you recognize that this is an *SMB* mount at all?