# Get 'Server' path or sever host name of mounted share in OSX

Tags: python, macos, share, mount, server-name

In OSX I have a mounted network share which is '`/Volumes/tmp`'. I would like to get the url or server host name of where the share is. So would like '`cifs://10.0.1.103/tmp`' or the server name. Not sure how to do this in Python 2.7 in OSX

Answer (score 0):

I found two answers on SO which suggest to use `df`: [Get 'unc' path in OSX of mounted share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848211/get-unc-path-in-osx-of-mounted-share/24874696#24874696) and [How do I get the server hostname from a mounted directory with cocoa/obj-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580253/how-do-i-get-the-server-hostname-from-a-mounted-directory-with-cocoa-obj-c/2580368#2580368)

The following code is an improved version of the first answer (my edit of which was obviously not approved):

```
import subprocess

df = subprocess.Popen(['df', '/Volumes/link/to/some/folder'],
                      stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
outputLine = df.stdout.readlines()[1]
uncPath = outputLine.split()[0]
print uncPath
```

Caveats: As far as I can see, this does not give you the protocol ("smb", but maybe that's implied for paths starting with two slashes) and I would rather like a solution that does not involve parsing (which might fail with spaces in user/server/share names).  My hunch was that one could try to ask the Finder about that information (e.g. via services, or maybe using pyobjc).

BTW: `smb://` and `cifs://` seem to be equivalent.  With OS X 10.9, I can use both with the `open` command to open remote shares, and I get the same `df` output and behavior.  If you stick a protocol in front of the `uncPath` in order to get a complete URL (or something that can be used with `open` later), this might be interesting.  Also note that `smb://`-style URLs should work on Linux (in KDE's and Gnome's file managers), too.

UPDATE: `df` on Linux has the behavior and output format for cifs mounts, so the same code works on Linux!